# Horizontal Slider X axis

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I have a container in which it is a horizontal scroll slider. I am just trying to figure how to show the element that is in the viewport at the time

I tried to look for left. I tried to put the slides in an array and look for the x axis but I am a little stumped.

This is my scroll function.

```js
const scroll = () => {
  const scrollContainer = document.querySelector('.slider');

  scrollContainer.addEventListener('wheel', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    scrollContainer.scrollLeft += e.deltaY;
  });
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <title>demo</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="slider hidden" id="slideshowContainer">
    <div class="innerSlider" id="innerSlider">
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1586023492125-27b2c045efd7?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=958&q=80" alt="" draggable="false" />
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1583847268964-b28dc8f51f92?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=687&q=80" alt="" draggable="false" />
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1586105251261-72a756497a11?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=958&q=80" alt="" draggable="false" />
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1618220048045-10a6dbdf83e0?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=880&q=80" alt="" draggable="false" />
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1513694203232-719a280e022f?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1169&q=80" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1513694203232-719a280e022f?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1169&q=80" alt="" draggable="false" />
      </div>
      <div class="slide">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1513694203232-719a280e022f?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1169&q=80" alt="" draggable="false" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Essentailly your are looking for a *web page horizontal scroll container*. *CSS-Tricks* offers a nice base example for you to start with [Pure CSS Horizontal Scrolling](https://css-tricks.com/pure-css-horizontal-scrolling/)

Comment: I am looking to find the div that my horizontal slider lands on so I can blow it up Full Screen!

Comment: By ‘horizontal slider lands on’ do you mean when the image starts to come into the viewport?

Comment: @haworth, yes when the image of the innerSlider comes into the viewport!